# Python: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.linear_model'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have been following a YouTube tutorial on machine learning and how to set up a web page for a simple project.

YouTube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q5JyawS8f5Q&t=683s

GitHub link: https://github.com/codebasics/py/tree/master/DataScience/BangloreHomePrices/server

In the script, I was using the pickle.load() method to load the machine learning model stored in a pickle file. However, I have been getting an error saying that there is no module named sklearn.linear_model. I have tried to import it manually on the same python file, but that also gives me an error as it seems as though PyCharm does not recognize the module.

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Code\BHP\server\util.py", line 30, in <module>
    load_saved_artifacts()
  File "C:\Code\BHP\server\util.py", line 24, in load_saved_artifacts
    __model = pickle.load(f)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.linear_model'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Code:

```
import json
import pickle


__locations = None
__data_columns = None
__model = None


def get_location_names():
    return __locations


def load_saved_artifacts():
    print("loading saved artifacts...start")
    global __data_columns
    global __locations

    with open("./artifacts/columns.json", 'r') as f:
        __data_columns = json.load(f)["data_columns"]
        __locations = __data_columns[3:]

    with open("./artifacts/banglore_home_prices_model.pickle", 'rb') as f:
        __model = pickle.load(f)

    print("Loading saved artifacts... Done.")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    load_saved_artifacts()
    print(get_location_names())
```

Text file:

```
{"data_columns": ["total_sqft", "bath", "bhk", "1st block jayanagar", "1st phase jp nagar", "2nd phase judicial layout", "2nd stage nagarbhavi", "5th block hbr layout", "5th phase jp nagar", "6th phase jp nagar", "7th phase jp nagar", "8th phase jp nagar", "9th phase jp nagar", "aecs layout", "abbigere", "akshaya nagar", "ambalipura", "ambedkar nagar", "amruthahalli", "anandapura", "ananth nagar", "anekal", "anjanapura", "ardendale", "arekere", "attibele", "beml layout", "btm 2nd stage", "btm layout", "babusapalaya", "badavala nagar", "balagere", "banashankari", "banashankari stage ii", "banashankari stage iii", "banashankari stage v", "banashankari stage vi", "banaswadi", "banjara layout", "bannerghatta", "bannerghatta road", "basavangudi", "basaveshwara nagar", "battarahalli", "begur", "begur road", "bellandur", "benson town", "bharathi nagar", "bhoganhalli", "billekahalli", "binny pete", "bisuvanahalli", "bommanahalli", "bommasandra", "bommasandra industrial area", "bommenahalli", "brookefield", "budigere", "cv raman nagar", "chamrajpet", "chandapura", "channasandra", "chikka tirupathi", "chikkabanavar", "chikkalasandra", "choodasandra", "cooke town", "cox town", "cunningham road", "dasanapura", "dasarahalli", "devanahalli", "devarachikkanahalli", "dodda nekkundi", "doddaballapur", "doddakallasandra", "doddathoguru", "domlur", "dommasandra", "epip zone", "electronic city", "electronic city phase ii", "electronics city phase 1", "frazer town", "gm palaya", "garudachar palya", "giri nagar", "gollarapalya hosahalli", "gottigere", "green glen layout", "gubbalala", "gunjur", "hal 2nd stage", "hbr layout", "hrbr layout", "hsr layout", "haralur road", "harlur", "hebbal", "hebbal kempapura", "hegde nagar", "hennur", "hennur road", "hoodi", "horamavu agara", "horamavu banaswadi", "hormavu", "hosa road", "hosakerehalli", "hoskote", "hosur road", "hulimavu", "isro layout", "itpl", "iblur village", "indira nagar", "jp nagar", "jakkur", "jalahalli", "jalahalli east", "jigani", "judicial layout", "kr puram", "kadubeesanahalli", "kadugodi", "kaggadasapura", "kaggalipura", "kaikondrahalli", "kalena agrahara", "kalyan nagar", "kambipura", "kammanahalli", "kammasandra", "kanakapura", "kanakpura road", "kannamangala", "karuna nagar", "kasavanhalli", "kasturi nagar", "kathriguppe", "kaval byrasandra", "kenchenahalli", "kengeri", "kengeri satellite town", "kereguddadahalli", "kodichikkanahalli", "kodigehaali", "kodigehalli", "kodihalli", "kogilu", "konanakunte", "koramangala", "kothannur", "kothanur", "kudlu", "kudlu gate", "kumaraswami layout", "kundalahalli", "lb shastri nagar", "laggere", "lakshminarayana pura", "lingadheeranahalli", "magadi road", "mahadevpura", "mahalakshmi layout", "mallasandra", "malleshpalya", "malleshwaram", "marathahalli", "margondanahalli", "marsur", "mico layout", "munnekollal", "murugeshpalya", "mysore road", "ngr layout", "nri layout", "nagarbhavi", "nagasandra", "nagavara", "nagavarapalya", "narayanapura", "neeladri nagar", "nehru nagar", "ombr layout", "old airport road", "old madras road", "padmanabhanagar", "pai layout", "panathur", "parappana agrahara", "pattandur agrahara", "poorna pragna layout", "prithvi layout", "r.t. nagar", "rachenahalli", "raja rajeshwari nagar", "rajaji nagar", "rajiv nagar", "ramagondanahalli", "ramamurthy nagar", "rayasandra", "sahakara nagar", "sanjay nagar", "sarakki nagar", "sarjapur", "sarjapur  road", "sarjapura - attibele road", "sector 2 hsr layout", "sector 7 hsr layout", "seegehalli", "shampura", "shivaji nagar", "singasandra", "somasundara palya", "sompura", "sonnenahalli", "subramanyapura", "sultan palaya", "tc palaya", "talaghattapura", "thanisandra", "thigalarapalya", "thubarahalli", "tindlu", "tumkur road", "ulsoor", "uttarahalli", "varthur", "varthur road", "vasanthapura", "vidyaranyapura", "vijayanagar", "vishveshwarya layout", "vishwapriya layout", "vittasandra", "whitefield", "yelachenahalli", "yelahanka", "yelahanka new town", "yelenahalli", "yeshwanthpur"]}
```

Please help me with how to resolve this issue. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have sklearn installed and which version?

if you don't have you can install by `pip install scikit-learn`

Comment: Yes, I have installed sklearn. The version is 1.1.1.

Comment: still try to install it by the command I mentioned above. Sorry I can not comment yet that is why I am writing answers

Comment: I tried the command on the command prompt. The command prompt says the requirements are satisfied. Are sklearn and scikit-learn the same things?

Comment: yes yes they are the same things. are you sure that the environment you install scikit-learn and the env you are running your file is the same? maybe you can also try `from sklearn import linear_model`

Comment: I tried to add that line in the program code, but PyCharm indicates an error and does not recognize the module.

Comment: That also happens when the version of the pickles differs meaning you had a different version of a pickle when you created that file and you have a different version of a pickle when you are trying to load. By any chance do you know the version of the pickle that created that file?

Comment: Both seem to use version 4.0 of Pickle. Additionally, I tried to change the conda environment version to 3.7 and did some guesswork tinkering with the pip package versions, and somehow, it miraculously works now, although I have no idea why it does. It still gives me a warning that I am using a different version of Flask than my model, but that is a compromise I am willing to live with. Thanks for the help along the way.

Answer (score 1):

The `pickle` module implements binary protocols for serializing and de-serializing a Python object structure.
From the error you can guess that pickle is having object/model from sklearn.linear_model package.
In order for unpickling the pickle u need to have every package which was used in the file which is pickled.

Hence, you need to install sklearn with `pip install scikit-learn`

Comment: I tried the command in both the command prompt and PyCharm terminal. They both say the requirements are satisfied. I then tried to install pickle just in case, and I got the following message: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pickle (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pickle

Comment: Try terminating any running console and restart it. If it still persist then it might be version error. In github you can find `requirement.txt` file. So in `python` you use `requirement.txt` file for mentioning every required package along with it's version. So you need to install those specific version of package.  try this command `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: So I added the requirements.txt to the project, and PyCharm seems to recognize that. However, the installation of the appropriate versions keeps failing. It seems as though my Python version is not compatible with those modules.

Comment: Can't help much then. You need to run appropriate Python version for packages to run.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to install `scikit/learn` is using the Anaconda Environments Option on the Anaconda.Navigator Suite. Go to the List Box and select Not installed. Then, go to the right corner and write `scikit/learn` on the searcher.  Then, check all the `scikit/learn` boxes that you need to install. Finally, click on the Apply button.